# syntax pytorch.nn functions neural networks, class or functions?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am puzzled by the syntax of the functions used in neural networks in pytorch.
Here is an example of how one can define a linear transformation layer: (cf. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html)

```
m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
input = torch.randn(128, 20)
output = m(input)
print(output.size())
torch.Size([128, 30])
```

Can someone explain me where the expression `nn.Linear(20,30)(input)` comes from ? It disturbs me a bit.

Indeed, one can define a class neural network with such cosntructor : (for example)

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes, p=0):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1            = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size, bias=True)
        self.fc2            = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size, bias=True)
        self.fc3            = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size, bias=True)
        self.fc4            = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes, bias=False)
        self.dropout        = nn.Dropout(p=p)
```

and I was trying to write an attribute using numpy function, like:

```
  self.enter_reshape  = np.reshape(-1, input_size * input_size)
  self.exit_reshape   = np.reshape(input_size, num_classes / input_size)
```

or, using the view function from pytorch:

```
self.reshape = view(-1, self.num_flat_features())
```

The closest thing I know about is the partial function and closures, where one could write `f(z)(x)(y)`. I looked into the definition of Linear, and I saw that linear is an object, but I don't see where they redefined `__call__` magic function, which I thought would be used here when one calls the object.

**So basically, can one explain what is up with such writting, and also, would it be possible to give to the neural network the numpy or view functions as attributes?**

Comment: It is basically `forward` function which gets called. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481130/14108734)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torch.nn.Linear` inherits from `torch.nn.Module` (see [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear)), which in turn defines `__call__` method.

You can see source code for `torch.nn.Module` [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L178). This class allows users to make their own `Modules` by inheritance (as you did in your example) and is a base for all PyTorch defined modules like `nn.Linear` (see available methods, documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html)).

Its `__call__` essentially calls `forward` but running registered hooks (and registering), checking `torchscript` etc. (see [source code here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L715), with relevant line [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L727).

> would it be possible to give to the neural network the numpy or view
> functions as attributes?

From the example you've given, what you are trying to do is probably `partial` function (or `lambda` as in the example below) saved as attribute (though that is pretty uncommon and never seen it tbh), like this:

```
import torch


class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, shape: int = -1):
        super().__init__()  # required
        self.reshape = lambda tensor: torch.reshape(tensor, (shape,))

    def forward(self, tensor):
        return self.reshape(tensor)


module = MyModule()
module(torch.randn(4, 5, 6)).shape # [120] shape
```

You shouldn't use `numpy` with `pytorch` **unless you really need it and/or there is no sensible pytorch counterpart** (although you can if you transform `torch.Tensor` to `numpy`). Also you shouldn't do anything like the code above as it's really confusing, just save attributes (anything like `input_shape`, `hidden_dim`, `output_size`) and use it in `forward`:

```
class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, shape: int = -1):
        super().__init__()  # required
        self.shape = shape

    def forward(self, tensor):
        return torch.reshape(tensor, (self.shape,))
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, it makes sense now. Also thank you for the pieces of advice. Would you recommand using `reshape` or `view` ? I have seen both, and I had the impression `reshape` is making a copy while `view` doesn't. Last point, are you recommanding to not use `numpy` because `pytorch` should be able to deal with it ? by another way.

Comment: `reshape` does copy if it's necessary, otherwise works like `view`. Provided by pytorch for closer API parity with `numpy`

Comment: @MarineGalantin Please accept this answer if this answer resolved your questions, thanks.

Comment: I will Szymon, I am still thinking, I am sorry for taking some time. Give me 24h.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Of course, just a reminder as a lot of people lately forget to do it saying "Thanks" instead.

Comment: Hey Szymon, thank you for your answer. There is in your example that phrase `lambda tensor: torch.reshape(tensor, (shape,))` i searched for it online, and i found tuple unpacking. Can you please explain me why there are brackets around shape? I have never seen it!

Comment: `(shape)` would just mean `shape` vairable, if you want one-element `tuple`, you have to use `(shape,)`. It is quite common practice to leave `,` after the last element as it's easier to add new element to such `list/tuple` afterwards (or for other people).